# Error while using currentView feature of Ember.ContainerView in an each helper

Tags: ember.js

I would like to be able to swap views in a each helper using Ember.ContainerView.

```
{{#each itemController="person"}}
  <li>{{view Ember.ContainerView currentViewBinding="cv"}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

It yields the following error:

> Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM

It does work when I strip off the each helper.

I know there is other ways to do that but it seems to me that it's a good use case for a ContainerView.

Here is the jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/fblanvil/Mr3D7/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something you did caused a view to re-render after it rendered but before it was inserted into the DOM

I found the problem, have a look at your modified and working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tD3Ph/).

Basically what you where doing wrong and thus the error was that you where calling `create` which should be rather `extend`.

See here for the changed part:

```
...
cv: Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'name'
})
...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But what I don't understand is that it does work without the surrounding each helper, see : <http://jsfiddle.net/fblanvil/Mr3D7/4/>

Comment: I guess it works without the `#each` helper because you have only one view to render, but in the case of the `#each` helper loop you should let the container views be instantiated at the right time when the binding mechanism kicks in

Comment: Sorry, are you still around ? I can't swap view after that. See that (jsfiddle)[http://jsfiddle.net/fblanvil/tD3Ph/2/] based on your corrected answer.

Comment: yep, what can I help you with?

Comment: Something strange is that when you look at the official guide, they do create the view.

Comment: well, to swap the view used in the `#each` loop seams to not be trivial, I'll have a closer look... in the mean time you could create a different question with the new problem and I'll get to it as soon as I can, also creating a new question will attract more eyes that do look at it

Comment: Yep, I'll put the link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515873/cant-swap-currentview-of-ember-containerview-in-a-each